# Is there an integral that proves that $\sin \tan 1\lt 1$?

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

I recently noted that this inequality is unbelievably sharp:

$$\sin \tan 1\lt 1$$

Is there some sort of integral that can prove that this is true?

This question might be of some use:

[Prove: $\sin (\tan x) \geq {x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642353/prove-sin-tan-x-geq-x)

I also noted, after seeing some of the comments, that an integral of $$\pi/2-\tan 1$$

would also greatly help

Comment: Since Henry's answer shows the inequality is easy, maybe your question should be about why the left side is so close to 1. [That maybe makes it a bit of a vague question, but that closeness seems to be the real surprise, IMO.]

Comment: What do you mean unbelievably? They are two reals, either they're equal or one is bigger than the other

Comment: Curious... does "sharp" mean that the inequality is "close" to being an equality? Is this term in common usage? Thanks!

Comment: What you may want an integral for is $\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan 1$.

Comment: @Ant What is unbelievable is not that they are unequal, but that they are nearly equal. I don't believe that this is obvious.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 as zahbaz says, I'm was not aware that sharp meant "very close" in this case. I am not sure how Henry answer does anything then, since (as far as I can see) not give any reason for the closeness of the two numbers (if there is indeed a "deeper" reason) :-)

Comment: If anyone does not have a calculator, the approximate values are $$1 - \sin\tan 1 = 0.0000896$$ and $$\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan 1 = 0.0134$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

- $\sin(x) \lt 1$ unless $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi$ for integer $n$

Comment: I was looking for an integral, but this is even nicer! I wonder how I missed this :)

Comment: You have to prove that $\tan 1\ne\pi/2$, though. `;-)`

Comment: Yes, that is true. In that sense, my question is still intact! I will make an edit, though