# Lower bound on $\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin(\tan x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

> Let$$I=\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin(\tan x)dx$$
> Show that the following lower bound holds: $$I\ge\frac{\pi^2}{32}$$

Right off the bat, I noticed that $\frac{\pi^2}{32}=\int_0^{\pi/4}xdx$. So the question begs the usage of:

$$\sin x\le x \le \tan x$$

However, trying to apply this leads to a chaotic inequality change:

$$I\ge \int_0^{\pi/4}\sin(x)dx \color{red}{\le}\int_0^{\pi/4}xdx$$

which is inconclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your idea, it suffices to show that $\sin(\tan(x)) \ge x$ on $[0, \pi / 4]$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642353/prove-sin-tan-x-geq-x) question.

Comment: Wow, I completely underestimated this monster. Thanks for the reference!